# can't install Realtek RTL8723de on ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.15

Tags: drivers, kernel, realtek-wireless

I did this:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-041500-generic

$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
Cloning into 'rtl8723de'...
remote: Counting objects: 536, done.
remote: Total 536 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 536
Receiving objects: 100% (536/536), 2.41 MiB | 356.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (195/195), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
DKMS: add completed.

$ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-041500-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-041500-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

I suspect is because the kernel 4.15 but i wanted to see what you think it is, im struggling with this the whole day
thanks
EDIT:
make.log

```
$ cat make.log 
DKMS make.log for rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 for kernel 4.15.0-041500-generic (x86_64)
mar ini 30 14:47:00 PET 2018
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-041500-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:287:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:316: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: * [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1514: recipe for target 'module/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build' failed
make[1]: * [module/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic'
Makefile:1884: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: @Jeremy31 will be better able to help you if you run: `cat  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log ` Next paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this page via Google, it is not necessary to downgrade the kernel, use the official drivers instead. See [this thread at the HP forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307) and the [instructions at the GitHub repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/blob/master/README.md).

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install

REBOOT
```

That's how I got this error fixed on my HP 14-bp071nd with rtl8723de and kernel 4.15.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem, the conclusion is that it doesn't work on kernel 4.15 so i downgraded to 4.14, the result was:

```
$ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.14.0-041400-generic..................
cleaning build area....

DKMS: build completed.

rtl8723de.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version v5.1.1.8_21285.20171026 for rtl8723de.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 4.14.0-041400-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
```