# Slow speed (wifi hotspot)

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

Recently installed ubuntu 18 LTS dual boot with win 7
getting the required speed on Windows but not on ubuntu.

Please help.
Waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice weak signal try
Code:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1
```

and see if it is better, if not do 
Code:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Source [Worked for me](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454)

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found

Comment: sudo apt-get --reinstall install module-init-tools

Comment: Hey even after installing module-init-tools; I'm getting the same error

Comment: @ShubhamPandey https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001536/cant-install-realtek-rtl8723de-on-ubuntu-16-04-kernel-4-15

Comment: How do I attach a screenshot in comments ?

Comment: @ShubhamPandey upload to some img site

Comment: This was the result https://drive.google.com/open?id=1djrUOecO3SlxDEfkIkUMgGildIz5aCT1

Comment: Please help me solve the problem